# Filter admin column wordpress with custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I use [this code](http://pastebin.com/AXvdS2Bd) to filter wordpress admin column with select box :

It filter well my posts and url generated by the code is like :

```
edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=offre_emploi&action=-1&m=0&ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME=contrat&ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE=CDD&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

but when meta value is a serialized value like : `a:1:{i:0;s:9:"secteur_7";}`inside database, i cannot get results.

Anyone, could advise me how is the URL formed when a query to serialized value?

Thank you

Comment: It's not possible. Rework your code so the value isn't serialized.

Comment: Hello, thank for reply so it is not possible to filter wordpress admin column from custom fields checkboxes, wordpress auto serialize checkboxes custom field.